# How DSpace process a query in jspui?

Tags: postgresql, dspace

How any query is processed in DSpace and data is managed between front end and PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2):

Like every other webapp running in a Servlet Container like Tomcat, the file WEB-INF/web.xml controls how a query is processed. In case of DSpace's JSPUI you'll find this file in [dspace-install]/webapps/jspui/WEB-INF/web.xml. The JSPUI defines several filters, listeners and servlets to process a request.

The filters are used to report that the JSPUI is running, that restricted areas can be seen by authenticated users or even by authenticated administrators only and to handle Content Negotiation.

The listeners ensure that DSpace has started correctly. During its start DSpace loads the configuration, opens database connections that it uses in a connection pool, let Spring do its IoC magic and so on.

For the beginning the most important part to see how a query is processed are the servlets and the servlet-mappings. A servlet-mapping defines which servlet is used to process a request with a specific request path: e.g. all requests to example.com/dspace-jspui/handle/* will be processed by org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.HandleServlet, all requests to example.com/dspace-jspui/submit will be processed by org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.SubmissionController.

The servlets uses their Java code ;-) and the DSpace Java API to process the request. You'll find most of it in the dspace-api module (see [dspace-source]/dspace-api/src/main/java/...) and some smaller part in dspace-services module ([dspace-source]dspace-services/src/main/java/...). Within the DSpace Java API their are two important classes if you're interested in the communication with the database:

- One is org.dspace.core.Context. The context contains information whether and which user is logged in, an initialized and connected database connection (if all went well) and a cache. The methods Context.abort(), Context.commit() and Context.complete() are used to manage the database transaction. That is the reason, why almost all methods manipulating the database requests a Context as method parameter: it controls the database connection and the database transaction.
- The other one is org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseManager. The DatabaseManager is used to handle database queries, updates, deletes and so on. All DSpaceObjects contains an object TableRow which contains the information of the object stored in the database. Inside the DSpaceObject classes (e.g. org.dspace.content.Item, org.dspace.content.Collection, ...) the TableRow may be manipulated and the changes stored back to the database by using DatabaseManager.update(Context, DSpaceObject). The DatabaseManager provides several methods to send SQL queries to the database, to update, delete, insert or even create data in the database. Just take a look to its API or look for "SELECT" it the DSpace source to get an example.

In JSPUI it is important to use Context.commit() if you want to commit the database state. If a request is processed and Context.commit() was not called, then the transaction will be aborted and the changes gets lost. If you call Context.complete() the transaction will be committed, the database connection will be freed and the context is marked as been finished. After you called Context.complete() the context cannot be used for a database connection any more.

DSpace is quite a huge project and their could be written a lot more about its ORM, the initialization of the database and so on. But this should already help you to start developing for DSpace. I would recommend you to read the part "Architecture" in the DSpace manual: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Architecture

If you have more specific questions you are always invited to ask them here on stackoverflow or on our mailing lists (http://sourceforge.net/p/dspace/mailman/) dspace-tech (for any question about DSpace) and dspace-devel (for question regarding the development of DSpace).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the version of DSpace you are running, along with your configuration.

- In DSpace 4.0 or above, by default, the DSpace JSPUI uses [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) for all searching and browsing. DSpace performs all indexing and querying of Solr via its [Discovery module](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Discovery). The Discovery (Solr) based searche/indexing classes are available under the "[org.dspace.discovery](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/tree/master/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/discovery)" package.
- In earlier versions of DSpace (3.x or below), by default, the DSpace JSPUI uses [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) directly. In these older versions, DSpace called Lucene directly for all [indexing](https://wiki.duraspace.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=32474035) and searching. The Lucene based search/indexing classes are available under the "[org.dspace.search](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/tree/dspace-3_x/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/search)" package.

In both situations, queries are passed directly to either Solr or Lucene (again depending on the version of DSpace). The results are parsed and displayed within the DSpace UI.